# Qual é a diferença de request e request.Session()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber a diferença de request e request.Session() do modulo requests.

Qual seria o uso ideal de cada um?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*O Requests é uma biblioteca HTTP para Python simples e elegante, feita para seres humanos. Você agora está vendo a documentação de versão de desenvolvimento.*

*O `Session()` permite você persistir alguns parâmetros através de requisições. Ele também permite persistência de cookies através de todas as requisições feitas a partir de uma instância de Session.*

Exemplo de persistência de alguns cookies através de requisições:

```py
    s = requests.Session()

    s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
    r = s.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies")

    print r.text
    # '{"cookies": {"sessioncookie": "123456789"}
```

Então resumindo, o `requeste` é a biblioteca e o `Session()` é o objeto dessa biblioteca usado para a persistência de cookie. Pode ler mais sobre [aqui](https://requests.readthedocs.io/pt_BR/latest/user/advanced.html), caso tenho mais duvidas sobre