# Python - Acessar sistema web

Tags: python, url, login

Fiz um script para acessar um sistema web com login e senha.

```
import requests
url = 'http://meuip:8080/login.xhtml'
values = {'username': 'user',
          'password': 'senha'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print (r.content)
```

Está funcionando, porém eu preciso acessar uma função desse sistema que só funciona se o usuário estiver logado.

Seria uma segunda URL: `http://meuip:8080/minha_funcao`

Eu achei que se incluí-se mais uma linha com url = '', já seria suficiente pra acessar a função.

Mas o retorno é que continua sem acesso, como se o login e senha só valesse para a primeira URL.

Não estou entendo como posso logar no sistema e ainda logado, chamar a segunda url.

Alguem se habilita?

Comment: provavelmente vai precisar utilizar cookies ( o que é retornado da rotina de login) para fazer o acesso ao segundo URL de uma maneira authenticada.

Comment: Estude sobre `requests.Session`

Comment: @Danizavtz e Woss agradeço o retorno, vou correr atrás dessas coisas. Assim que eu chegar num resultado eu posto aqui.

Answer (score -3):

isso é um pouco mais complicado, depende como o site esta estruturado.

o requests não salva os dados que você acessou como um histórico para deixar dados salvos, ele faz uma chamada. É como se você abrisse um navegador, chamasse, e logo fechasse.

o que você vai ter que fazer é: fazer a chamada e guardar os dados, como cookies, headers, etc.

então na segunda chamada, para verificar se esta logado, você envia os dados.

mas ai depende tambem, você tem que ver quais dados o site pede, isso você pode ver facil indo pro navegador e inspencionando o headers, payload e cookies.

então você vai ter que usar 2 chamadas, mas salvar os dados da primeira para simular um sistema logado.

recomendo você olhar: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/370750/qual-é-a-diferença-de-request-e-request-session](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/370750/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-request-e-request-session)